# Laravel 5 package: publish config from `require` package entry

Tags: laravel, package

While creating a Laravel 5.x package I need to modify a config entry from one of my `require` packages. I can't just run `php artisan vendor:publish` since there is none so is there some way to publish the config files of my packages?

The package in question I want to publish is `rcrowe/twigbridge`.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation sais:

> TwigBridge's configuration file can be extended in your ConfigServiceProvider, under the `twigbridge` key. You can find the default configuration file at `vendor/rcrowe/twigbridge/config`.

You can try to copy the `twigbridge.php` from `your-project/vendor/rcrowe/twigbridge/config/twigbridge.php` to `your-project/config/twigbridge.php` and then add it to your ConfigServiceProvider:

```php
public function register()
{
    config([
        'config/twigbridge.php',
    ]);
}
```